# Office 365 API: Add a contact to an organisation distribution list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, office365

I've been tasked to provide functionality to an ASP.NET MVC that allows users to enter their email address, press submit button, and their email address will be added to an existing distribution group existing in an Office 365 account.

I'm not overly familiar with the Office 365 API, and I have searched but cannot find anything that really helps me.

I'm reaching out to the SO community for help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't currently modify group membership via the Office 365 APIs. The only way to do this currently is via PowerShell.